# bower and npm after web deploy

Tags: iis, web-deployment, microsoft-web-deploy

Is it possible to run "npm install" and "bower install" on an IIS server running web deploy after deployment?

I tried the following approach but it didn't work out:

```
<ItemGroup>
<MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">
  <Path>&quot;bower install&quot;</Path>
</MsDeploySourceManifest>
</ItemGroup>
```